# Regex Find Text Between Tags C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to strip the html tags and only return the text between the tags. Here is what I'm currently using.

```
string regularExpressionPattern1 = @"<td(.*?)<\/td>";
Regex regex = new Regex(regularExpressionPattern1, RegexOptions.Singleline);
MatchCollection collection = regex.Matches(value.ToString());
```

I currently get `<td>13</td>`, and I just want `13`.

Thanks,

Comment: Don't do this with a regular expression, instead use an HTML parser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get value of group not of the match.
Try this

```
Match m = collection[0];
var stripped = m.Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Also you missing closing bracket for opening td tag.

Answer (score 6):

You can use look-behind `?<=` and look-ahead `?=` like this:

`(?<=<td>)(.*?)(?=<\/td>)`

That should give you just the text between the tags. More info on Regex and look-ahead/look-behind can be found [Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Also, a good Regex tester can be found [Here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/). I use it to test all my Regex strings when I'm writing them.

Comment: This is a viable solution and will work. I have tested it. Was there a reason for the down-vote?

Answer (score 3):

So, using the [HTML AgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), this would be really easy...

```
 HtmlDocument  doc = doc.LoadHtml(value);
 var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td//text()");
```

Puts the TextNodes in the  nodes variable.

Comment: Which is exactly what `//text()` does, it only takes the text nodes, removni all markup.

Comment: An innocent mistake I promise, sorry for that. Anyway the OP's have funny taste on what to accept sometimes even when you tell them what's right.

Comment: Doesn't matter, as long as this answer gets upvoted massively.

Answer (score -1):

use 
    match.Groups[1].Value